# So i'm trying to have it check to see if the steamid64 all ready exists before inserting but it just inserts any way?

Tags: php, mysql, steam

So i'm trying to have it check to see if the steamid64 all ready exists before inserting but it just inserts any way?
i'm not good with PHP here.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","Gmod");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$SteamID64 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['SteamID64']);
$enable = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['enable']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM Loading (SteamID64, enable) WHERE SteamID64='$SteamID64'";
 if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1) {
echo'<center>The music is already disabled!</center>';
}
else {
$sql="INSERT INTO Loading (SteamID64, enable)
VALUES ('$SteamID64', '$enable')";
}

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "<center>The music will not play when you connect.</center>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

i got this off some forums and w3schools.com
and edited it.

Ok so i did this but its still just inserting the data?

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","server","Gmod");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$SteamID64 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['SteamID64']);
$enable = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['enable']);

mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Loading WHERE SteamID64='$SteamID64'");
 if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query)>=1) {
echo'<center>The music is already disabled!</center>';
}
else {
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Loading (SteamID64, enable)
VALUES ('$SteamID64', '$enable')");
}
echo "<center>The music will not play when you connect.</center>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Just a note, please do not use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated. You can use the `mysqli_*` functions (procedural or OOP style) or `PDO` (abstraction layer).

Comment: That's not really helping me here.

Comment: Do not mix `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: So i just need to add i to the end  of mysql_* so like mysqli_*?

Comment: It is not the same name for all functions, but in this case yeah you should use `mysqli_num_rows` and pass the query resource (which you'd get from a `mysqi_query` that is missing in your code) as first parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you cannot mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions like that (pick one, `mysqli_*` and stick to that), you have an error in your sql:

```
SELECT * FROM Loading (SteamID64, enable) WHERE SteamID64='$SteamID64'
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this should not be here
```

You need to change that to:

```
SELECT * FROM Loading WHERE SteamID64='$SteamID64'
```

You can have mysqli throw exceptions so that it tells you exactly what went wrong when it goes wrong. Just add this to the top of your script:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Another problem you have, is that the execution of your second query should be inside the `else` part of the previous condition.

And as @FabrícioMatté already mentioned, you actually need to execute your query using `mysqli_query()`, just setting the string does not do anything.

Comment: The code in the question is also missing a `mysqli_query`, and   `mysql_num_rows` should be `mysqli`.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Thanks, I added your first point, the second one was already mentioned in the comments and in the first line of my answer.

Comment: Oh ok, you can be more clear saying "You have to execute the query before calling `mysqli_num_rows`" and a 2 lines code block could help illustrating.